# How do I unhide the Mail preview pane?

Tags: mail.app

In my default view when using Apple's [Mail](https://support.apple.com/mail) on [macOS](https://support.apple.com/macos), I used to see 3 coluns, from left:

1. Mailbox
2. Inbox
3. Email

I stretched the Inbox column / pane to width of the full window, and now have only 2 columns:

1. Mailbox
2. Inbox

I cannot "pull back" the Email pane with a mouse.

How can I restore the missing Email preview pane?

Answer (score 3):

You have moved the divider line to the right to set the email pane to zero width. You move it back the same way, *but you have to move to almost full width* for it to "hold", after that you can vary the width as you like.
It is the same in Classic View: if you do not move it up very high it will not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Note: while moving it to almost full width, it doesn't look like the divider is moving at all - the email panel will just suddenly appear when you've pulled it long enough.